# JavaScript - Looping through elements and checking for length

Tags: javascript

I have some code that goes through the elements that end in '_ro' as below:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id$=_ro]").forEach(function(element) {
element.readOnly = true;  
});
```

Is there a way I can check to see if there is an input, and if there is a value input, set it to read only?

Comment: What do you mean *empty* ?

Comment: `if(element.value.length) element.readOnly = true;` ?

Comment: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id$=_ro]"), function(element) {
element.readOnly = element.value.trim() !== '';  
});`

Comment: "if there is an input" - you can add input in selector "input[id$=_ro]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `element.nodeName == 'INPUT'` to check the node name and  `element.value.length` to check the value length:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[id$=_ro]").forEach(function(element) {
  if(element.nodeName == 'INPUT' && element.value.length)
    element.readOnly = true;  
});
```

```html
<input id="name_ro" type="text" value="Jhon"/>
<div id="div_ro">test</div>
<input id="phone_ro" type="text"/>
```